# How much SEF have to be the URLs?

Tags: seo

I'm really attracted to the [webservice.js](https://github.com/marak/webservice.js) module. I'd like to use it as a real webserver, using only an HTML page with JS calling the webservice to retrieve the datas.

The problem I'm seeing is about the search engines, as I do wish my website to be search engine optimized.

So I thought I could be fallbacking to plain HTML when JS is not enabled (just going to the url, webservice.js sends back some datas in plain HTML). For this, the links will be displayed in the HTML markup on the frontpage.

The problem is about how much SEF have the URLs to be?

I mean, the webservice will allow me to have URLs of this kind : http://domain.com/content?get=title-uri-encoded.

Is it search-engine friendly? I know having http://domain.com/content/title-uri-encoded would be better, but is the kind I'm thinking of still friendly?

PS : I'm not sure whether this post belongs to SO or Programmers.se...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into progressive enhancement techniques or Google's proposed AJAX solution.

You may end up with a URL structure like this:

AJAX enabled public version

http://domain.com/content#!get=title-uri-encoded

Search Engine version (plain html)

http://domain.com/content?_escaped_fragment_=get=title-uri-encoded

Comment: Yeah... I know about that, but that's not the question. The question is rather "how friendly have the URLs to be?". Maybe I should make myself clearer?

Comment: Search engines only have problems when a URL contains lots of parameters that have lots of values and variations. your single parameter with keyword rich data is good.

Comment: Ok, got my answer then, thanks :)